# Implications of LC_ALL=C to speedup grep

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I just discovered that if i prefix my grep commands with a LC_ALL=C it does wonders for speeding grep up.

But i am wondering about the implications.

Would a pattern using UTF-8 not match?
What happens if the grepped file is using UTF-8?

Comment: What version of grep? There was a nasty UTF bug somewhere before 2.7.1 or 2.7.3. I am assuming its GNU grep, BSD grep is always slow.

Answer (score 18):

You don't necessarily need UTF-8 to run into trouble here. The locale is responsible for setting the character classes, i.e. determining which character is a space, a letter or a digit. Consider these two examples:

```
$ echo -e '\xe4' | LC_ALL=en_US.iso88591 grep '[[:alnum:]]' || echo false
ä
$ echo -e '\xe4' | LC_ALL=C grep '[[:alnum:]]' || echo false
false
```

When trying to match exact binary patterns against each other, the locale doesn't make a difference, however:

```
$ echo -e '\xe4' | LC_ALL=en_US.iso88591 grep "$(echo -e '\xe4')" || echo false
ä
$ echo -e '\xe4' | LC_ALL=C grep "$(echo -e '\xe4')" || echo false
ä
```

I'm not sure about the extent of grep implementing unicode, and how well different codepoints are matched to each other, but matching any subset of ASCII and the matching of single characters without alternate binary representations should work fine regardless of locale.

Comment: So if i read this right: the files to grep & the list of patterns contain only ascii characters, everything should be fine?

Comment: Yes, you’ll be fine with pure ASCII. At least in practice, as in theory it could be EBCDIC.

Comment: what is `||`? some kind of if statement?

Comment: If I'm understanding this answer correctly, does it mean it's never a danger to use `LC_ALL=C`, and it should be preferred to other locales?