# Cron Job on Unix SSH server : UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: php, unix, utf-8, ssh, cron

Running in PHP 5, I have tried the following two commands to upload from a ISO-8859-1 string to a UTF-8 database that links to UTF-8 web pages:

```
$data[] = utf8_encode((string)$child);
```

... or:

```
$data[] = convertToUtf8((string)$child);

function convertToUtf8($text) {
//  cURL('http://'.$url);

    preg_match('/<meta.*?charset=(|\")(.*?)("|\")/i', $html, $matches);

    $charset = $matches[2];

    if($charset)
        return mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', $charset);
    else
        return $text;
}
```

If I execute the PHP script directly by accessing the file from the browser, either one of these works like a charm : the « é » imported is its nice French self. HOWEVER, when I try to execute the same script from a Unix terminal SSH (cron job OR command line), it does not convert the code and so the « é » shows up as « Ã© ».

Any ideas?? I've tried deleting the cron job and replacing the script to make sure the code was going through. This is getting maddening!

Update - the solution

It turns out this particular functionality needs a later version of PHP. Executing it in the Terminal with the following command (and writing the command as such in the cron job) takes care of the problem:

```
php5.4 xmluploader.php
```

Comment: the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138124/implications-of-lc-all-c-to-speedup-grep should give you some idea of how to approach this. I would search for `LC_ALL french` and hope you can find a closer answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, along the way I certainly got to explore some encoding insights but in the end, the solution was quite embarrassingly simple.

I was running the job by typing in

```
php myjob.php
```

That was a non-starter, because the version by default on my server was too primitive and did not contain the functions utf8_encode or mb_convert_encoding. Therefore, I now start the job with the following command:

```
php5.4 myjob.php
```

... and it works like a charm.